# Spring JMS - How to define Connection Proxy

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I want to define a proxy for a connection to Azure Service bus using aqmp.
I'm in a Springboot app, v1.5, and I'm using Apache qpid-jms-client.

Actually, I'm declaring a JmsTemplate bean that receive a CachingConnectionFactory.

How to define a proxy with CachingConnectionFactory (Or any other connectionFactory implementation) ?

Thanks

Comment: I want to know this as well, too bad any questions concerning this has no answers whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

There was an update on the jar which now allows proxies .

Check this out :
[How to create connection to AMQP queue over SSL using SOCKS proxy or any other proxy in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803510/how-to-create-connection-to-amqp-queue-over-ssl-using-socks-proxy-or-any-other-p)